# Make Virtual Machine stop working

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

is there some program to make a vmware virtual machine stop working in x days?
My problem is: a user need to share a VM with a partner with our product license to a training. I need to make this VM stop working X day.
can you help me?

thank you
Regards

Comment: are you trying to "share" your product license with a third party?

Comment: Would it be enough to simply add a startup script that checks whether X days have passed and then resets the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use VMware Workstation Pro's "restricted VM" feature (VM > Settings > Options > Access Control), you can set the VM to expire after a certain date.

Comment: Thank you!, but i was looking for opensource sw becouse i cant buy a license only for this user.

Comment: @Antonio Note that you could use VMware Player to run a restricted VM created with Workstation.  VMware Player isn't open source, but it is free for non-commercial use if that helps.